# Explanation of the Generalist badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The explanation of the Generalist badge is “Active in many different tags”. This explanation is less clear then the ones of other badges. Especially what does *many* mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [relevant information](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/) why nobody is awarded generalist badge in stats.SE. The **top 40 tags must have at least 200 questions** for the badge to be awarded. So although there are people who satisfy the requirements of the badge, the stats.SE as a site does not, since currently only one tag **r** has more than 200 questions. So it will be quite a when this badge will be awarded, although when it does, quite a few people will immediately qualify.

Comment: (+1) Nice catch!

Comment: +1 Finally, an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, our 40th badge appears in 35 questions, so we're about 1/6 of the way there.  Nobody is going to get a generalist badge during the next three or four years (aka the infinitely far future) unless site activity goes way, way up.  So, as far as any of us is concerned, this badge doesn't exist.

Comment: @whuber, in this particular case I would argue that the minimum question requirement should be adapted for each site according to traffic. Otherwise this badge does not make sense.

Comment: Agreed.  There are many legitimate ways to establish better quantitative criteria for this badge (and many others).  It raises interesting questions about the stability of the ranks in a dynamic, growing sample.  I'm sure good statistical thinking would be helpful not only here but in all the analytical aspects of the SE sites.

Comment: @whuber -- re: "*Nobody is going to get a generalist badge during the next three or four years (aka the infinitely far future) unless site activity goes way, way up*" - as it was, the first one was awarded just over 18 months later, and a dozen people had it by the end of 2012 (16 have it now) -- I suppose the site activity must indeed have gone way up.

Comment: @Glen_b It did.  Mods can see graphs of activity metrics over time, such as numbers of Q's & A's, pageviews, etc. (but are asked not to disclose details).  By almost any measure, this site's usage has increased fivefold since April 2011, whereas at that time usage had actually plateaued for several months.  There's a lesson here somewhere about making time series forecasts :-).

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm wrong, it means "Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags".

Comment: Hmm.. Then it seems you should have received this badge long ago.

Comment: @whuber You're largely above me about that! :-)

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist

I think we failed to update the description on all the other sites. This is a bug.

Comment: Did you also update the algorithm on this site?  It seems we have several people who likely have qualified.

Comment: @whu no known problems with it at this time. But it is a very hard badge to get; much larger sites only have ~20 users with the badge.

Comment: That's what I thought.  However--for instance--the ["Generalist progression" query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/s/880/generalist-progression) says @chl has 15 or more points in 25 of the top 40 tags on this site.  There are other users with even greater progression toward this badge.  But nobody here has been awarded it.  Is there perhaps a problem with the query?

Answer (score 2):

All badge descriptions for the generalist badge have been updated to match Stack Overflow.